# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i am trying to use jquery autocomplete component.i want to show images in autocomplete.so i have to write _renderMenu and _renderIItem function.i wrote a code :

```
 var _filterUser = $('#filterUser').autocomplete({
                    source: onEditLoadUsers,
                    select: onEditSelectUser,
                    focus: onEditFocusUser
                }); 
 $('#filterUser').data("autocomplete")._renderItem= function( ul, item ){
    console.log('coming here');
    return $( "<li>" )
           .append( $( '<img src="'+item.photo+'" />' ) )
           .appendTo( ul );
 };
 $('#filterUser').data("autocomplete")._renderMenu= function(ul,items){
     var that = this;
     console.log('ul is')
     console.log(ul);
     console.log(items);
     $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
         that._renderItemData( ul, item );
     });                       
 };
```

if i remove _renderItem function and _renderMenu function then simple autocomplete is working but when i add these two function it gave me error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function FullCalendar?sfdc.tabName=01ri0000000sqRT:359
(anonymous function) FullCalendar?sfdc.tabName=01ri0000000sqRT:359
v.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
$.data._renderMenu FullCalendar?sfdc.tabName=01ri0000000sqRT:358
a.widget._suggest jquery-ui.min.js:5
a.widget.__response jquery-ui.min.js:5
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:5
onEditLoadUsers FullCalendar?sfdc.tabName=01ri0000000sqRT:779
a.widget._search jquery-ui.min.js:5
a.widget.search jquery-ui.min.js:5
(anonymous function)
```

i am using jquery 1.8.3 and jquery UI 1.8 .Please guideline how to resolve this error ??

Comment: that._renderItemData( ul, item ); did you mean _renderItem(ul, item)?

Comment: No i mean _renderItemData as you can see in http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ i copy pasted this code.using _renderItemdata is mandatory in _renderMenu i think.

Answer (score 1):

You can not extend the object in such a way.

Try this way:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    var ac = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype;
    if (typeof $.uix !== "object") { $.uix = {}; }

    ac = $.extend({}, ac, {
        _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
            console.log('coming here');
            return $("<li>")
                .append($('<img src="' + item.photo + '" />'))
                .appendTo(ul);
        },
        _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
            var that = this;
            console.log('ul is')
            console.log(ul);
            console.log(items);
            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                that._renderItemData(ul, item);
            });
        }
    });

    $.uix.autocomplete = ac;
    $.widget("uix.autocomplete", $.uix.autocomplete);
})(jQuery);
```